# Observer pattern, smart pointers and singleton classes

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to create an Obserer pattern using smart pointers. This is my class:

```
class Observable {
public:
    void addObserver(std::shared_ptr<Observer> ptr);
private:
    std::list<std::weak_ptr<Observer>> observers;
};
```

The use of smart pointers provides strong guarantees about memory leak, however I don't understand how to manage list of observers when I don't have a `shared_ptr`. Example for singleton classes:

```
class Singleton {
private:
  Singleton();
public:
  static Singleton& getInstance() {
      static Singleton instance;
      return instance;
  }
}
```

In this case I don't have a shared ptr but the singleton class can be an observer. Does it mean that I need to return a shared_ptr from a singleton class? Is there any design detail to take into account?

Comment: If you want to return a `shared_ptr` as a singleton class, take care about the thread safety. Creating a pointer using `std::make_shared` is not thread safe by default and you should handle it yourself.

Comment: @Gupta Using C++11 the static allocation on first call is thread safe and granted by standard.

Comment: You mean having something like this? `static std::shared_ptr<Singleton> = std::make_shared<Singleton>()`?

Comment: or just shared ptr constructor using "new" of Singleton class.

Comment: @greywolf82 Using a shared_ptr is supposed to automagically delete the pointed object one day or another. But in the case of the singleton you really don't want that to happen (static allocation). I'm affraid the two design choices are incompatible.

Comment: @prog-fh I had the same feeling

Comment: the comment of @Gupta seems to be a solution. Just return the copy of this static shared_ptr so the singleton is always referenced at least once by this static variable but not copied (just the shared_ptr is)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a different strategy:

```
class ObserverWrapper: public Observer {
public:
  void notify() override {
      ref.notify();
  }
private:
  Observer& ref;
};

class ObserverProxy: public Observer {
public:
    operator std::shared_ptr<Observer>() {
       return wrapper;
    }
    ObserverProxy() : wrapper(std::make_shared<Observer>(*this) {
    }
private:
    std::shared_ptr<Observer> wrapper;
};

class Singleton: public ObserverProxy {
public:
  void notify() override {
      //something here
  }
};
```

Now I can do:

```
Singleton& s = Singleton::getInstance();
Observable obs;
obs.addObserver(s);
```